# Second loopback network interface (for netem)

Tags: networking, loopback

I would like to add a second loopback network device on Linux, so that I have `lo` and (e.g.) `lo2`. This is so that I can use [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) to simulate a throttled network over lo2 without compromising my standard loopback interface.

Note that I can not use an alias interface here (such as lo:1) since netem will affect the underlying (lo) interface, not the interface alias.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you add a [virtual tap device](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) and do the testing on that?

```
ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap
```

You may need to insert the `tun` module first.

```
modprobe tun
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't do. The net 127.0.0.0/8 is *always* loopback (127.0.0.1 is just conventional). This is enforced by the kernel.